# Align one label in contact form to the top line instead of the middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my contact form I have several labels and input fields.  The "Message" label default apparently is in the middle next to it's 5-line input text area.  I'm trying to align that one label to the top line. `vertical-align: top` doesn't work.

How can I align this one label to the top line, not the middle?

Here's my code for the form:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<form method="post" role="form">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="contact-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </div>


    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="col-md-12  form-group">
        <label for="name">your name</label>
        <span class="fieldSpan">
                          <input type="text" 
                          name="name" 
                          id="input-field-name"
                          class="form-control" 
                          placeholder="your name" 
                          value=""> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
              <div class="contact-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              </div>

              <div class="form-inline">
              <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="email">your email address</label>
                      <span class="fieldSpan">
                      <input type="email" 
                      name="email" 
                      id="input-field-email"
                      class="form-control" 
                      placeholder="yourname@website.com" 
                      value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
         </div>

        <div class="row">
              <div class="contact-icon">
                  <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
              </div>
        
              <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="message">your message</label>
                        <span class="fieldSpan vertical-align:top">
                        <textarea name="message" 
                        rows="5" 
                        id="input-field-message"
                        class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="your message">
                        </textarea>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `align-self: flex-start` since Flexbox is used here.

```css
.message-row .form-inline label {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<form method="post" role="form">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="contact-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </div>


    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="col-md-12  form-group">
        <label for="name">your name</label>
        <span class="fieldSpan">
                          <input type="text" 
                          name="name" 
                          id="input-field-name"
                          class="form-control" 
                          placeholder="your name" 
                          value=""> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
              <div class="contact-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              </div>

              <div class="form-inline">
              <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                      <label for="email">your email address</label>
                      <span class="fieldSpan">
                      <input type="email" 
                      name="email" 
                      id="input-field-email"
                      class="form-control" 
                      placeholder="yourname@website.com" 
                      value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
         </div>

        <div class="row message-row">
              <div class="contact-icon">
                  <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
              </div>
        
              <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="message">your message</label>
                        <span class="fieldSpan vertical-align:top">
                        <textarea name="message" 
                        rows="5" 
                        id="input-field-message"
                        class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="your message">
                        </textarea>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: YES! It worked!  OMG. That had been driving me crazy for hours.  Thank you so much.  You rock!   (I guess I need to learn more about flexbox.)